# Alternative imageUrl for fzaninotto/Faker

Tags: php, testing, symfony4

The function imageUrl() in library https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker does not work anymore

```
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
            {
                
                $faker = Factory:: create('FR-fr');
                
                for ($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++) 
             {     
                    $title = $faker->sentence();
                    $coverImage = $faker->imageUrl(1000, 350);
             }
```

what is the alternative?

Comment: _the function imageUrl() does not work anymore_ is not a very useful problem description. Could you share error message(s) and debugging efforts?

Comment: Hi ack, i want to display random images. And the site (lorempixel.com
) where these images are loaded no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, i found the following solution :

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $faker = Factory:: create('FR-fr');

    for ($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++) 
 {
        $title = $faker->sentence();
        $coverImage = "https://picsum.photos/1200/350?random=".mt_rand(1, 55000);
 }
```